# Android NDK - GPS и WiFi

Tags: android, wifi, android-ndk, c++, gps

Подскажите, как с помощью Android NDK работать с GPS - получать координаты и Wifi - получать информацию о доступных точках доступа.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно и насколько я посмотрел - явно нельзя. Если доступ и найдете, то только к конкрентым устройствам.

Мои предложения :

1. Возможно вам не нужен NDK.
2. На NDK можно написать обработку, а математику пишете на NDK.
3. Из NDK можно вызывать java классы. Оно конечно не быстро. [вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8530924/how-to-call-java-api-from-ndk-c-thread).